# Reduced pronunciation of "and" and "to"

Tags: pronunciation

I am listening to [Econ Talk with Thomas Sowell (Uncut)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gDS2SzOUSog).

At around [0:10](https://youtu.be/gDS2SzOUSog?t=10s), I think he says "Economics and liberty" but "and" sounds almost "n".  Is this common?

At around [0:25](https://youtu.be/gDS2SzOUSog?t=25s), is he saying "links and other information" or "links to other information"?

Again, the sound between "links" and "other" sounds like "n"

Comment: Like `Guns N' Roses`? Yes it is common.

Comment: @norbertpy  Thanks. And at 0.27, what is he saying? links "and" other information? links "to" other information?  Does "to" often sound "n" , too?

Comment: I can't tell but it sounds more `links and other information` to me as `to` will have a sharp sound that I don't hear in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pronunciation of "and" is very often shortened to just the "n" sound, especially in less formal settings (or settings where the speaker wishes to portray less formality).  This even happens in names, like Shop 'N' Save, Guns 'N' Roses, etc.
This happens in both of the cited instances (the second one is definitely 'and' rather than 'to').